# How prove this inequality $[f(x)]^2+[f'(x)]^2\le \max{(A,B)}$

Tags: analysis

> let $f(x)$ be two derivable on $R$,give the two postive  numbers $A,B$ and such
>   $$[f(x)]^2\le A$$
>   $$[f'(x)]^2+[f''(x)]^2\le B$$
>   show that
>   $$[f(x)]^2+[f'(x)]^2\le \max{(A,B)},\forall x\in R$$

I think maybe well know inequality： 
$$|f'(x)|\le2\sqrt{|f''(x)||f(x)|}\le |f''(x)|+|f(x)|$$
$$\Longrightarrow [f'(x)]^2\le (|f''(x)|+|f(x)|)^2\le\dfrac{1}{2}([f''(x)]^2+[f(x)]^2)$$

if $A\ge B$
then I can't
$$[f(x)]^2+[f'(x)]^2\le A$$

Maybe this idea can't usefulll?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that: $(f(x))^{2} + (f'(x))^{2} \leqslant \max(a,b)$ where $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677427/prove-that-fx2-fx2-leqslant-maxa-b-where-a-b-in-mat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$. Then $g'(x)=2f'(x)(f(x)+f''(x))$. It is sufficient to verify $g(x)\le\max\{A,B\}$ at critical points and as $x\to \pm\infty$.. At critical points of $g$ we have

- either $f'(x)=0$. Then $g(x)=f(x)^2\le A$.
- or $f(x)+f''(x)=0$. Then $g(x)=f(x)^2+f'(x)^2=f''(x)^2+f'(x)^2\le B$.

As $x\to \infty$ beyond critical points, $g'(x)$ has constant sign, hence $f'(x)$ does not cross $0$ and so $f$ is monotonic. Since $f$ is bounded, we conclude that $a:=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists. 
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given, wlog. $\epsilon<\frac12$. Then there exists $x_0$ such that both $|f(x)-a|<\epsilon$ and $|f^2(x)-a^2|<\frac12\epsilon$ for all $x>x_0$. Then for any $x>x_0$ we have $f(x+2)-f(x)=2f'(\xi)$ for some $\xi\in(x,x+2)$. For this $\xi$ we conlcude $|f'(\xi)|<\epsilon$ and then  $g(\xi)=f(\xi)^2+f'(\xi)^2$ differs from $a^2$ by less than $\epsilon$. As it lacks critical points, we must have $g(x)\to a^2\le A$. The same argument works as $x\to-\infty$.